# what is difference between Sql server 2008 Developer version and Sql server 2008 expess edition

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want to know about the difference in this two version

1. Sql server 2008 Developer edition
2. Sql server 2008 expess edition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See this http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx:

> SQL Server 2008 Developer enables developers to build and test applications that run on SQL Server on 32-bit, ia64, and x64 platforms.
>
> SQL Server 2008 Developer includes all of the functionality of Enterprise Edition, but is licensed only for development, test, and demo use. The license for SQL Server 2008 Developer entitles one developer to use the software on as many systems as necessary.
>
> For rapid deployment into production, instances of SQL Server 2008 Developer can easily be upgraded to SQL Server 2008 Enterprise without reinstalation.

Comment: `Build and test applications by using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer, which takes advantage of all the functionality in the premium Datacenter edition but is licensed only for development, test, and demo use.` http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/developer.aspx

Comment: As of 12.09.2013 the provided link does no more show any information about Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer.

Answer (score 7):

The quick answer is that Express Edition has several limitations in terms of features, but you can freely use it in a live system. Developer edition has every feature of the Enterprise edition, but you can only use it in development, not in any live systems.